# opensuse network management undefined

Tags: networking, opensuse

I did an update on my opensuse box and networking stopped working.  The system is trying to use networkmanager, even though it isn't installed.  I am using yast to try and get it to use ifup, but it complains about no network connection.  I tried running:

```
ifup eth0
```

and I get back:

```
Network is managed by '' -> skipping
```

Does anyone out there know why it is coming back empty and if there is a config file that I can manually tweak to fix this?

Comment: Shiquemano, this site is for software development related queries. You should flag it so it gets migrated to a more appropriate site such as superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are running 12.3 or 13.1 with systemd.

Disable network manager if it exists: 
*systemctl disable networkmanager.service*

Enable network.service: 
*systemctl enable network.service*

Make sure ifcfg-eth0 exists with a configuration in /etc/sysconfig/network/

Run *ifup eth0*

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help someone. 
1. Disable NetworkManager, Stop is and then enable it and restart it respectively.
2. All this happens in console. Check the status for NetworkManager and in the status messages it should show that the interface(wierless) is disconnected. Confirm this by typing command "sudo nmcli c"
3. Type command "sudo iwlist (wireless-interface) scan" to show you the available wireless networks
4. If you see the network that you want to connect to listed, type command "nmcli a" and enter the corresponding connect phrase/password to connect